# Python - Run multiple python scripts from main file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a python script, and from the python script I must launch multiple python scripts that must run all at one time.  It would be preferred for the other scripts to run in the background and feed the input back to the main console.  This must work on all major OSes.  Also, it is critical to run them simotaneously, otherwise I would use defs.
Running python 2.7.8, by the way.

Update:
Sorry for title mismatch.  Cookies glitched or something.  I currently have a main script, which i need to run several more python scripts from all at once, and return the output live to the main window.  If you can think of another way that is os-inspecific that can do that, let me know!

Update 2:
I found a solution:
        var=subprocess.Popen(['python', 'file.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        for line in favTL.stdout"
            print line

Comment: Your description has nothing to do with the title. You can do this type of thing with subprocess and potentially the daemon module. But its more than a few lines of code. You need to give an example of what you've done and narrow your question to problems in that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into the python `thread` module?

```
thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])
```

will start a new thread in parallel. You can either import the other python files and call the specific functions you want, or run the whole script with

```
subprocess.call( ["python", "file.py"] )
```

...though making shell calls will be slightly less portable between OS's.

Comment: ill take a look!  Does it allow also writing the results to the main terminal?

Comment: Yup, a process and all of its sub-threads will all print to the same terminal.

Comment: Great!  I'll test it soon.  Just to be sure, it works with Mac, Win, and Linux?

Comment: Yup, the `thread` module is completely internal to python, so OS doesn't matter at all if you're only using `thread`. `subprocess` however is making system calls, so varies a little bit, for example  `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'folder\file.py']` on Windows, but `subprocess.Popen(['python', 'folder/file.py']` (different slash) on Mac and *nix.